# Practicing Baking textures Problems

Tags: baking

I was working on a model and tried to bake the texture but didn`t work well so I decided to practice on a simple cube with just a basic noise texture. Baked it and then I plugged into the shader to see the result. It did bake it but the noise is different then the original texture why is that? thank you for your help
[image: Original texture]

[image: Baked]

Comment: Use the 'Normal Map' node instead of the 'Bump'

Comment: Damn it was that simple! Thank you very much!

Comment: Just another question. When creating an image texture for normal how should I set up Alpha and 32-bit Float?

Comment: Alpha for normal maps are unnecessary. 32-bit Float could result in a better normal map quality since it stores information more precisely, but it's also more computation heavy. I would say it depends on the use case